# Cannot find 'FirebaseApp' in scope using Carthage instead of CocoaPods

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, config, carthage

there days i've been migrating my app's dependency management software from CocoaPods to Carthage and the thing is **I don't know how to import "Firebase" module** since there is no binary named **FirebaseCore** or only **Firebase**

The following content is from my cartfile

```
github "Alamofire/Alamofire" ~> 5.4.3
github "realm/realm-cocoa" ~> 10.12.0
github "onevcat/Kingfisher" ~> 6.3.1
github "hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager"
binary "https://dl.google.com/dl/firebase/ios/carthage/FirebaseAppCheckBinary.json"
binary "https://dl.google.com/dl/firebase/ios/carthage/FirebaseAuthBinary.json"
binary "https://dl.google.com/dl/firebase/ios/carthage/FirebaseRemoteConfigBinary.json"
```

and everything is working but in my AppDelegate when I try to:

```
FirebaseApp.configure()
```

It returns the following error:
`Cannot find 'FirebaseApp' in scope` 
since I cannot import the module Firebase which is available in CocoaPods.
I have tried including different binaries from [this link](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/Carthage.md) without any results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while I discovered that in order to access FirebaseApp as well as Firebase module for importation, you must include the binary for FirebaseAnalytics, which appears to contain the FirebaseCore and Firebase modules.

```
binary "https://dl.google.com/dl/firebase/ios/carthage/FirebaseAnalyticsBinary.json"
```

after adding that to Cartfile, you only need to `import Firebase` in your AppDelegate and then FirebaseApp.configure() will work again.